# PHP form verification doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a html form with php verification but trying to submit the form with at least one filled textfield will say that the emails dont match (self made part of the code that should not be displayed.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  //File Verification

if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password1']) && empty($_POST['password2']) && empty($_POST['email1']) && empty($_POST['email2']) && empty($_POST['bday'])){
    echo"Kom op, vul alles in";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=register.php' />";
    exit();

}
else{
    $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if(email1 == email2){
        if(pass1 == pass2){

        }
        else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=register.php' />";
            echo"Je wachtwoorden komen niet overeen";
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=register.php' />";
        echo "Je email gegevens komen niet overeen";
        exit();

    }

}


}
else{


$form = <<<EOT
<form method="post" action="register.php">
Gebruikersnaam:     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="type hier je gebruikers naam"/><br /><br />
wachtwoord:         <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="type hier je wachtwoord"/><br /><br />
wachtwoord opnieuw: <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="type je wachtwoord opnieuw in"/><br /><br />
email:              <input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="type hier je email"/><br /><br />
email opnieuw:      <input type="text" name="email2" placeholder="type hier je email opnieuw"/><br /><br />
Geboorte datum:     <input type="date" name="bday"/ placeholder="type je geboorte datum hier"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>


EOT;

echo $form;
}
?>
```

It just shows

```
else{
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=register.php' />";
        echo "Je email gegevens komen niet overeen";
```

Comment: Isn't that what your code does? You do an equality check between the 2 email values and if they don't match, you get the else condition. Edit: just noticed you missing the $ symbols. See answer by @zzzareck

Comment: error reporting should be throwing you undefined constant xxx notices, but you decided to turn it off `error_reporting(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
    if(email1 == email2){
    if(pass1 == pass2){
```

to:

```
    if($email1 == $email2){
    if($pass1 == $pass2){
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo `pass1 == pass2`. 
Also, you may want to change from:

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) &&...
```

to

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) OR...
```